# Count number of files in a folder per day

Tags: command-line, find

I can find number of all files in folder but I got pretty large number.

```
find . -type f | wc -l      #find number of files in DIR
ls -lrt                     #list all files order by date
```

How to find number of files par day?

So, the result should be something like:

```
# left number is number of files and right is one day.

109294 2016-06-27
101555 2016-06-26
88123  2016-06-25 
... etc.
```

Comment: And what's the numbers on the left ?  `109294` and `109294`

Comment: Sry, That is the number of files per day.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do this using the `printf` action of `find` to print only the modification times in desired format, and then using `sort` and `uniq`:

```
find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

- `-printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n'` prints the modification time of files in e.g. `2015-05-23` format
- `sort` sorts the output and `uniq -c` does the count by date

**Example:**

```
~/foobar% find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | sort | uniq -c
      3 2004-06-29
      1 2004-08-23
      1 2004-09-15
      1 2004-09-18
      1 2005-07-24
      1 2006-02-05
      2 2008-06-25
      3 2008-12-31
      1 2009-03-13
      1 2009-04-30
      1 2010-04-04
      2 2010-09-01
      8 2011-07-13
     15 2011-08-27
      3 2011-11-03
      3 2014-10-08
```

Comment: NB: these can be viewed graphically with Gnuplot using `find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' 2</dev/null | sort | uniq  -c | tail -n +2 | gnuplot -p -e "set xdata time; set timefmt \"%Y-%m-%d\";set xtics rotate; plot '-' using 2:1 with impulses"`

Comment: Interesting way, but it doesn't work. I got an graphic but with no data...

Comment: This is great, but can also also leave a lot of whitespace at the front of the line. I used this: `find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{$1=$1};1' > rate.txt`, which removed that whitespace and writes the output to a file. Removing the whitespace helped me load `rate.txt` into python.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution with `find` + `awk`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | awk '{array[$0]+=1}END{ for(val in array) print val" "array[val]   }'
```

Essentially what happens is that we find all regular files and print their modification time as specified by the `%T` format , and then `awk` takes over , and  counts each line  using associate arrays . the `END{}` statement uses `for` loop to go through all the elements in the associated array, and print key + array[key] contents ( which is the date + count ).

You may want to use `sort` to organize the output , particularly `sort -k 1` based on column 1 (which is date), but that is optional. Also `-maxdepth 1` will check for files *only in the current folder*. If you want to find files in subdirectories as well, remove `-maxdepth 1` part.

Sample output

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | awk '{array[$0]+=1}END{ for(val in array) print val" "array[val]   }'

2015-09-29 1
2016-04-06 2
2016-04-07 10
2016-04-08 2
2015-11-05 2
2016-04-22 2
2016-04-23 6
2016-04-24 1
2015-11-21 2
2015-11-22 2
```

Comment: This might run faster than the `|sort | uniq -c` version, especially with very huge numbers of files and a small-ish set of different days.  Collapsing down to counts in one step avoids sorting a large number of duplicates before counting.